# What exactly can trigger a state change with Angular UI Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have added the onExit callback to one of my states and have found that my app is exiting and re-entering my state in cases where I didn't think it was. I have looked over their docs but I haven't found anything that explains exactly what can cause a state transition.

I have something like this

```
$stateProvider
  .state('ParentState', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/parent',
    data: {
      flow: 'Parent'
    },
    views: {
      'main': {
        template: indexTpl
      }
    },
    onExit: function() {
      console.log('onExit');
    }
  })
  .state('ChildState', {
    parent: 'ParentState',
    url: '?a&b',
    resolve: {
      resolvedData: ['$stateParams', 'service', function($stateParams, service) {
        service.resolveData($stateParams);
      }
    },
    views: {
      ...
    }
  };
```

The behavior I am noticing is that I'll be in /parent?a=something&b=somethingElse and then trigger something where a or b get changed to different values and this causes the resolve to run again. I would not expect 'ParentState' to exit since the variables are changing in the child state however onExit is being called.

I want to know what cases can trigger a state change so that I can use the onExit callback and know exactly when it will be called.

Comment: The reason the parent onExit callback was being called as well was because in calling state.go I passed in { reload: true } so I think this was causing both the child and parent states to exit and re-enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider),

> A state corresponds to a "place" in the application in terms of the
>   overall UI and navigation. A state describes (via the controller /
>   template / ***view properties***) what the UI looks like and does at that
>   place.

Therefore if the view properties change, the state changes from a `ChildState` to another `ChildState`. Then, because `ChildState` inherits `ParentState`, `onExit` is resolved for the first `ChildState`.